# 2 column web to 1 column mobile with dynamic height boxes

Tags: javascript, html, css, grid, flexbox

How can I css this diagram while supporting IE11 and all major browsers?

Flexbox doesn't seem to support dynamic height.

Do I have to have left/right columns for lg viewport and no columns for xs viewport?

[Codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/JrawwY?editors=1100)

```
<div class="container">
   <div id="box1" class="box">box1</div>`
   <div id="box2" class="box">box2</div>`
   <div id="box3" class="box">box3</div>`
   <div id="box4" class="box">box4</div>`
   <div id="box5" class="box">box5</div>`
</div>
```

[image: diagram]

Comment: There are many ways to do this. You can use a combination of [CSS Media Queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries) and [flexbox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Using_CSS_flexible_boxes) with polyfills where needed if you want to create a grid system for yourself. Or you could use any of the widely available grid system frameworks like [Simple Grid](http://simplegrid.io/) [Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/) [Bulma](http://bulma.io/) or [Foundation](https://foundation.zurb.com/) to name a few

Comment: Not sure what you mean by flexbox does not support "dynamic height". In my experience, you can coax almost any grid layout out of flexbox by playing with `flex-direction` `flex-wrap` `justify-content` and `align-items`

Comment: all rows start at the same vertical position.
I need the items inside each column to start wherever the last item ended. In the codepen you can see the space between box2 and box4

Comment: Just noticed that the DIV order changes in mobile view. One possible solution would be to render both layouts and selectively hide one using a media query.

Comment: You can't do that with Flexbox and dynamic height, either add script or use CSS Grid or float.

Comment: How can I achieve this layout using css grid?

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in my comment, you can render both and show only one layout based on the current screen size using media queries.

Sample Hack Implementation:

```html
<html>

<head>
    <style>
        .container {
            width: 100%;
        }

        .row {
            display: flex;
            flex-direction: row;
            justify-content: flex-start;
            width: 100%;
        }

        .column {
            display: flex;
            flex-direction: column;
            justify-content: flex-start;
        }

        .item {
            width: 100%;
            border: solid 1px #dadada;
            border-radius: 16px;
            display: flex;
            justify-content: center;
            align-items: center;
        }

        @media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
            .desktop-only{
                display: none;
            }
            .column{
                width: 100%;
            }
        }

        @media screen and (min-width: 601px) {
            .mobile-only{
                display: none;
            }
            .column{
                width: 50%;
            }
        }

        .item-1 {
            height: 200px;
        }

        .item-2 {
            height: 400px;
        }

        .item-3 {
            height: 250px;
        }

        .item-4 {
            height: 300px;
        }

        .item-5 {
            height: 350px;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="desktop-only">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="item item-1">1</div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="column">
                    <div class="item item-3">3</div>
                    <div class="item item-5">5</div>
                </div>
                <div class="column">
                    <div class="item item-2">2</div>
                    <div class="item item-4">4</div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="mobile-only">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="column">
                <div class="item item-1">1</div>
                <div class="item item-2">2</div>
                <div class="item item-3">3</div>
                <div class="item item-4">4</div>
                <div class="item item-5">5</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Breakpoint is set to 600px. Change window width above and below 600px to see the layout "change"